# Displaying all but the last line in a text file

Tags: vb.net, file, eof

I've created this 2 player game called Go and I've made it so that the statistics from the game is recorded in a text file. If the same 2 players play each other more than once, their game will be recorded in the same text file on the next line.

I have done all of that, but now I want the previous games to be displayed on screen so that the players can see the scores from previous matches. I don't want the final line to be displayed as that is the score from the game that has just finished. Here's my code so far:

```
 Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    'Imports the data from previous forms to form 3
    handikomi = Form1.handi_komi
    prisonerB = Form2.prisonerB
    prisonerW = Form2.prisonerW
    bpass = Form2.bpass
    wpass = Form2.wpass
    bstones = Form2.bstones
    wstones = Form2.wstones
    btotalscore = prisonerB + handikomi(0, 2)
    wtotalscore = prisonerW + handikomi(1, 2)

    If btotalscore > wtotalscore Then
        winnerlbl.Text = (handikomi(0, 0) & " IS THE WINNER!")
    ElseIf wtotalscore > btotalscore Then
        winnerlbl.Text = (handikomi(1, 0) & " IS THE WINNER!")
    End If

    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("F:\My Go project flood fill2\Text files\" & handikomi(0, 0) & " VS " & handikomi(1, 0) & ".txt", True)
    'Displays statistics from current match
    file.WriteLine("BLACK" & "," & "WHITE" & "," & "Total Score" & "," & btotalscore & "," & wtotalscore & "," & "Prisoners" & "," & prisonerB & "," & prisonerW & "," & "Passes" & "," & bpass & "," & wpass & "," & "Stones" & "," & bstones & "," & wstones)
    file.Close()

    breakdwnlbl.Text = "                    BLACK   WHITE"
    breakdwnlbl.Text = (breakdwnlbl.Text & vbNewLine & "Total Score" & "     " & btotalscore & "          " & wtotalscore)
    breakdwnlbl.Text = (breakdwnlbl.Text & vbNewLine & "Prisoners" & "         " & prisonerB & "          " & prisonerW)
    breakdwnlbl.Text = (breakdwnlbl.Text & vbNewLine & "Passes" & "             " & bpass & "          " & wpass)
    breakdwnlbl.Text = (breakdwnlbl.Text & vbNewLine & "Stones" & "              " & bstones & "          " & wstones)


    Dim data As String       'to hold value of file line 
    Dim filename As String   'declare file
    filename = "F:\My Go project flood fill2\Text files\" & handikomi(0, 0) & " VS " & handikomi(1, 0) & ".txt"  'path to file on system

    FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input)  'open file for reading
    'try amend
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        data = LineInput(1)
        MsgBox(data)
    Loop
```

I think that I shouldn't be using EOF for this case, but I don't know what else to use as I'm still a beginner. I appreciate any help!

Comment: did you tried to create a extra file with a list of the past games?

Comment: @MarcoSadowski what do you mean by an extra file? I've only created 1 file which contains all the previous games between the same 2 players with the same username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to read all lines and just skip the last one:

```
Dim allLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
Dim allButLast = allLines.Take(allLines.Length - 1)
```

The variable `allButLast` is an `IEnumerable(Of String)` containing all the lines of the file, except for the last one.

**Update:**

Here's an example to show each line in a `MessageBox`:

```
For Each line As String In allButLast
    MessageBox.Show(line)
Next
```

Comment: I get a build error with "file.ReadAllLines" when declaring the first variable. It's saying its not a member of streamwriter

Comment: Look closer at the code,  you should type `File` not `file`. With `File` I mean the class in the `System.IO` namespace.

Comment: I did write it with a capital f, but it automatically replaces it with a lower case f... EDIT: Ignore what I've just written, I realised I had created a variable named "file" which was messing with it. Thanks for the help!